Не активируются плагины в wordpress ошибка: Activation failed: 0
не один плагин не активируется выдает ошибку Activation failed: 0, плагины устанавливаются но не активируются.
отключил все плагины но не помогло, активировал другую тему тоже не помогло.
На странице всех плагинов если выбрать "активировать" то плагин активируется
Если активировать установленный elementor и elementor pro, то другие плагины даже не устанавливаются выдает ошибку:Installation failed: Download failed. Unauthorized. elementor pro не обновляется Version 3.11.2. elementor обновился Version 3.20.3.
wordpress 6.5
Вот что выдает debug.log
[03-Apr-2024 09:45:52 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: RequiresPlugins in C:\OpenServer\domains\auras.loc\wp-includes\class-wp-plugin-dependencies.php on line 565
[03-Apr-2024 09:45:52 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: RequiresPlugins in C:\OpenServer\domains\auras.loc\wp-includes\class-wp-plugin-dependencies.php on line 569
Сайт сделан на платной тебе WPocean стоит много платных плагинов, все станицы сделаны на elementor клиент просит добавить функционал который можно реализовать с woocommerce, но elementor не хочет с ним работать, редактор зависает и страница не открывается для редактирования предлагает безопасный режим, его включение не помогает. Короче не сайт а сплошная проблема. Может у кого было подобное подскажите что можно сделать?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.


что можно сделать? - Отдать такой сайт специалисту.

